# Email Postgres Query Output

Tags: postgresql

I would like to send out a weekly email to two or three users containing the output of a select statement, run against Postgres. Very simple select all statement to show the number of users in the system.

I am able to query the database via command line and see the result, but not email those results to someone. Is there a script that can be used for this task or a better approach? This is the code I ran to test connection to the database and see if I could pull data from it. Using PostgreSQL 9.1

This solution is for Windows Server 2008.

Comment: What OS are you using via command line to run the above script?

Comment: I tested on Centos, but the ultimate goal is to use Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what OS you're using, but on Ubuntu I wrote a modified version of your script and piped the output to mail (which, of course, requires that mailutils be installed):

```
psql -U username -d databasename -c 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM table' | mail -s "query results" someone@someplace.com
```

This worked just fine for me.

Comment: Hi Bobby, thanks for the reply. I will use your code to test. I started playing with unix, but my end goal is to have this solution on windows server, where the prod database resides.

Comment: The trick on Windows will be having a mail client that you can execute from a script.  There are many to choose from.  Blat seems to be popular.